# How to list available functions in the static library file

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi, static-libraries

I use Raspberry Pi 3 and program GPIOs using C and Sysfs/WiringPi.

If someone provides a static library (.a file) to work with my Raspberry Pi C project,
is there a way to list what functions, with what parameters needed, are available inside this static library?

For instance, if I get `"test.a"` without any documentation/explanation of it,
I want to find out that this static library has

```
void foo(int param1);
char bar(void);
```

Comment: Something from `binutils` will probably help. I'd start with `nm`.

Comment: While the question is similar to the "duplicate" one, mind that with just `nm` you can only get `foo` and `bar` for these functions (assuming C linkage), no parameter or return types.

Comment: `If someone provides a static library (.a file) to work with my Raspberry Pi C project` then this person provides the `.h` file as well.

Comment: And hopefully some usable documentation as well.